# jQuery code, not understanding

Tags: jquery

I am looking at this code and as I'm new to web design I'm unable to understand it.

So on my index page I have a link to google and the `ext.js` page the following code.

This is what I understand which is wrong.

The user clicks `ok` or `cancel`, therefore the variable `c` is either `ok` or `cancel`. Now I don't see the point of the `if` statement, because it will be either `ok` or `cancel` on other words true or false.

```
$(window).unload(function(){
    var c = confirm('Are you sure you want to leave?');
    if(c){ 
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: so why is the if statement used. the if statement doesn't make sense to me.  if(c) c is either true or false then it should return true.

Comment: c does equal to true or false because its equal to what the user clicks on

Comment: In addendum to the good answer below... It returns false if you click cancel to cancel the unload event.

Answer (score 10):

> the variable c is either ok or cancel

No, it will be `true` or `false` depending on which of OK or Cancel (or whatever the local i18ned version is for the browser in question) was pressed.

> i dont seee the point of the if statement

There isn't a point to it.

```
return confirm('Are you sure you want to leave?');
```

… gives the same result, much more concisely.