# not understanding simple jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that depending on what i press in the confirmation box the if-statement changes.

if i press ok, the c turns to true. Therefore it returns true ( takes me to the other page)

however c could either be true or false depending on what i press, so what would happen if i click cancel.

I mean in the if statement?

```
$(window).unload(function(){

var c = confirm('Are you sure you want to leave?');
if(c){ 

    return true;

}else{

    return false;

}
    });
```

Comment: i think the dialog box that comes up only has yes and no buttons. You know what happens when user clicks either of it.

Comment: Could you not have asked this in your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388112/jquery-code-not-understanding

Answer (score 0):

When you click `Cancel`, the `confirm()` call will return false (stored in `c`). Returning `false` from `.unload()` will stop the browser navigating away from the page you're executing on.